# CDS protection/contingent leg pricing, taking expectation of interest and hazard rates

Tags: finance-mathematics, pricing, mathematics, cds, pricing-formulae

[The Pricing and Risk Management of Credit Default Swaps, with a Focus on the ISDA Model](https://quant.opengamma.io/Pricing-and-Risk-Management-of-Credit-Default-Swaps-OpenGamma.pdf)
[Screenshot: Pricing protection leg of a CDS, by OpenGamma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5oHV.png)

In the screenshot above, I am having trouble understanding the maths between equation 13 and equation 14.

Notation:

- $N$ = notational payment, e.g., £100
- $RR$ = recovery rate, the percentage of the $N$ recovered upon default, e.g., you get back 40%
- $\tau$ = time of default
- $t_v$ = valuation date
- $T$ = maturity date
- $\mathbb{I}_A$ = indicator function for event $A$
- $r(s)$ = instantaneous short rate at time $s$
- $P(t)$ = discount factor from time $t > 0 = $start date
- $Q(t)$ = survival probability at time $t$

What I have tried:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\int_{t_v}^{T}r(s)ds}\mathbb{I}_{\tau<T}\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tau e^{-\int_{t_v}^{T}r(s)ds}\mathbb{I}_{\tau<T} d\tau = \int_{0}^{T} \tau \frac{P(\tau)}{P(t_v)}d\tau$$

From here, I cannot see how equation 14 is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more trying, I think I have it. 
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
N(1-RR)\ \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{-\int_{t_v}^{\tau}r(s)ds} \mathbb{I}_{\tau<T} \right] & = N(1-RR)\ \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{P(\tau)}{P(t_v)} \mathbb{I}_{\tau<T} \right] \\
 & = \frac{N(1-RR)}{P(t_v)}\ \mathbb{E}\left[ P(\tau) \mathbb{I}_{\tau<T} \right] \\
& = \frac{N(1-RR)}{P(t_v)}\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\frac{dQ(s)}{ds}P(s) \mathbb{I}_{s<T} ds \\
& = -\frac{N(1-RR)}{P(t_v)}\ \int_{0}^{T} P(s) \frac{dQ(s)}{ds} ds \\
& = -\frac{N(1-RR)}{P(t_v)}\ \int_{0}^{T} P(s)\ dQ(s)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Ciao!   why a minus appears in the third line? (in the same line I think you should put $s$ instad of $\tau$ in the characteristic function).

Comment: The minus appears there because derivative of the survival function is the negative of the density. Thank you for pointing out the mistake in the subscript.